# Delete ng-model input value in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have question about ng-model in ng-repeat.
I prepared example.

https://jsfiddle.net/0ff3btv2/1/

Basicaly I can create ng-model in input and delete its value by clicking button like this:

```
   <ul ng-controller="deleteCtrl">
     <li>
       <input type="text" ng-model="valueModel" placeholder="enter value" />
       <input type="button" ng-click="deleteValue()" value="Delete" />
     </li>    
   </ul>
```

However when use ng-repeat and do the same, value can't be deleted.

```
<ul ng-controller="deleteRepeatCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="element in data">
    <input type="text" ng-model="element.valueModel" 
                placeholder="{{element.firstName}}" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="deleteRepeatValue()" value="Delete"/>
  </li>    
</ul>
```

Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

try this instead of function

```
<input type="button" ng-click="element.valueModel=null" value="Delete"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this just pass the current element to controller

```
 <input type="button" ng-click="deleteRepeatValue(element)" value="Delete"/>

        </li>    



   $scope.deleteRepeatValue = function(element){
        element.valueModel = '';
    };
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e302vgg2/1/)

Comment: @jsPadawan accept it as a answer if it works for you :)